# Cyanogenmod is dead. Are there any android phones that I could just download AOSP and compile it instead of using LineageOS?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, aosp

I know Cyanogenmod has turned into LineageOS, but I just had a completely different idea: I would like to know if there's a phone that I can have root builtin, compile AOSP and flash it. Is there a list or blog post somewhere that shows which phones and models are AOSP compatible? Or am I stuck with only Nexus and Pixesl line?

Can I create zip updates like Cyanogenmod used to have, or all updates erases my device? Anyone here has experience on this?

Comment: No, AOSP does not include any drivers/low-level firmware for anything other than the Google flagship devices.

Comment: What grudge do you hold against LOS? It's practically CM - the maintainers stay the same.

Comment: You can have a root in cm it's just a sepaeate zip, not big deal..